# Increment value of a hash field in Redis using Python

Tags: python, redis, redis-py

I have created a `hash` in redis in python as follows:

```
r.hmset('list:123', {'name': 'john', 'count': 5})
```

How can I increment the value of count for the key `list:123`?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
r.hincrby("list:123", "count", 1)
```

Use this page for reference

https://redis.io/commands/hincrby

Comment: I think the point is not to overwrite what's already there. More of a read+write op, like hincrby.

Answer (score 11):

```
hash = 'list:123'
key = 'count'
n = 1

r.hincrby(hash, key, n)
```